# Insert colA into DF1 with vals from DF2['colB'] by matching colC in both DFs

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV files, CSV_A and CSV_B.csv. I must insert the column (Category) from CSV_B into CSV_A.

The two CSVs share a common column: StockID, and I must add the correct category onto each row by matching the StockID columns.

This can be done using merge, like this:

```
dfa.merge(dfb, how='left', on='StockID')
```

but I only want to add the one column, not join the two dataframes.

CSV_A (indexed on StockID):

```
StockID,Brand,ToolName,Price
ABC123,Maxwell,ToolA,1.25
BCD234,Charton,ToolB,2.22
CDE345,Bingley,ToolC,3.33
DEF789,Charton,ToolD,1.44
```

CSV_B:

```
PurchDate,Supplier,StockID,Category
20201005,Sigmat,BCD234,CatShop
20210219,Zorbak,AAA111,CatWares
20210307,Phillips
20210417,Tandey,CDE345,CatThings
20210422,Stapek,BBB222,CatElse
20210502,Zorbak,ABC123,CatThis
20210512,Zorbak,CCC999,CatThings
20210717,Phillips,DEF789,CatShop
```

My task is to insert a `Cat` field into CSV_A, matching each inserted Category with its correct StockID.

**Note1:** CSV_A is indexed on the StockID column. CSV_B has the default indexing.
**Note2:** There are some columns in CSV_B (e.g. row 3) that do not have complete information.
**Note3:** Adding column "Category" from CSV_B into CSV_A but calling it "Cat" in CSV_A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map `'Category'` based on `'StockID'`

```
df_a['Cat'] = df_a['StockID'].map(dict(zip(df_b['StockID'], df_b['Category'])))
```

Note that for this specific question *(i.e. with CSV_A indexed on StockID),* the code must be:

```
df_a['Cat'] = df_a.index.map(dict(zip(df_b['StockID'], df_b['Category'])))
                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: I like this solution, I prefer it, but how do you deal with the fact that df_a's index is 'StockID' *(which is why I was using `.name` in my answer).*  When I use your solution as-is, I get `KeyError: 'StockID'`, and when I substitute `df_a.name.map` I get: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: `df_a.index.map`? @cssyphus https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html

Answer (score 0):

While creating the question I discovered the solution, so decided to post it rather than just deleting the question.

```
import pandas as pd
dfa = pd.read_csv('csv_a.csv')
dfa.set_index('StockID', inplace=True)
dfb = pd.read_csv('csv_b.csv')

#remove incomplete rows (i.e. without Category/StockID columns)
dfb_tmp = dfb[dfb['StockID'].notnull()]

def myfunc(row):
    # NB: Use row.name because row['StockID'] is the index
    if row.name in list(dfb_tmp['StockID']):
        return dfb_tmp.loc[dfb_tmp['StockID'] == row.name]['Category'].values[0]
dfa['Cat'] = dfa.apply(lambda row: myfunc(row), axis=1)

print(dfa)
```

Result:

```
StockID Brand   ToolName    Price   Cat
ABC123  Maxwell ToolA       1.25    CatThis
BCD234  Charton ToolB       2.22    CatShop
CDE345  Bingley ToolC       3.33    CatThings
DEF789  Charton ToolD       1.44    CatShop
```

Comment: loops are very slow, you should try avoid it